# Wait for callback to run before throwing result firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Im using react-native, Expo and firebase firestore
I have tables

**products**

- id
- name

**items**

- id
- productId
- expirationDate

I want to get all the products and the amount of items that product has.
Code is:

```
export const getProducts = (callback) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  let products = [];

  db.collection('products').get().then((productsSnapshot) => {
    productsSnapshot.forEach((_product, index, array) => {
    let product = _product.data()

    product.id = _product.id;
    getItems(product._id, (items, error) => {
      product.count = items.length;
      products.push(product);
    });
  });
  callback(products, null);
  ...

export const getItems = (productId, callback) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  let items = [];

  db.collection('items').where('productId', '==', productId).get()
  .then((itemsSnapshot) => {
    itemsSnapshot.forEach((_item) => {
      let item = _item.data();
      item.id = _item.id;

      items.push(item);
    });

    callback(items, null);
    ...
```

The problem I have is the callback on getItems runs after and .count never gets a value.

I tried async await but I couldn't understand how to use it and threw errors while using firestore. Is using callbacks a bad idea? What is the way it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could surround it by a promise, and put the callback in the then. Something like this...

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection('products').get().then((productsSnapshot) => {
        productsSnapshot.forEach((_product, index, array) => {
            let product = _product.data()
            product.id = _product.id;
            getItems(product._id, (items, error) => {
                product.count = items.length;
                products.push(product);
            });
        });
        resolve();
    });
}).then(function () {
    callback(products, null);
});
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to do a bit more than this actually. Because looks like you don't want to call the resolve() until all your getItems return as well. But promises will solve your problem.

You can do Promise.all([ promise1, promise2 ]).then(function() { });

where you put multiple promises in the array and the then doesn't get called until they all resolve

Comment: There is no other way apart from promises? Maybe making it async and waiting for getItems ... ???